# Setting up the Delay Jobs gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, delayed-job

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I am trying to setup the [delay_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem for my web application in order to send emails in this way:

```
Notifier.delay.send_email(@user)
```

As well as written in the official gem documentation, to start my "delayed jobs" I should use one of the following line of code

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop

# Runs two workers in separate processes.
$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n 2 start
$ RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop
```

or invoke the `rake jobs:work` task.

In production mode I prefer to use one of the `RAILS_ENV=...` statements, but I would like to know *where (that is, in which file) I should add that code* in order to start the workers on application start (BTW: at this time I am not using Capistrano to deploy my application).

More, I would like to know what exactly "workers" are and if my VPS hosting (running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) can run multiple of those or how to know how many workers my server can run.

Finally, I would like to know what options can I add in the `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb` file and if there are some advices or tricks about the Delay Job gem.

Comment: What do you mean by ""automatize" the initialization process"? You mean start the workers on application start? As far as VPS and worker requirements go we cant answer that because we dont know what the workers are running and what type of VPS you have. Please post some code.

Comment: @Devin M - Yes, I mean start the workers on application start. What code I should post since I am not asking a question about specific coding issues in my application?

Comment: You asked abut how many workers you can run that is dependent on what type of code you are running in the workers. As far as application start let me work up an answer for you.

Comment: @Devin M - In the workers I am running things like `Notifier.delay.send_email(@user)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start your workers on application start I would just call the proper command from an initalizer. The code to do this would look like:

```
system "RAILS_ENV=production #{Rails.root.join('script','delayed_job')} stop"
system "RAILS_ENV=production #{Rails.root.join('script','delayed_job')} -n 2 start"
```

The path might be a little off and there most likely is a cleaner way to do it but I dont know of anything off of the top of my head.

Comment: If, for example, I restart my Apache2 server will my workers stop working and then re-start or those will run continuously (that is, they overlap)? And, referring to others question, what options can I add in the Delay Job initializer file?

Comment: Well your workers will continue runnin until they die naturally. If the application restarts however the workers if still running will be stopped and started again to prevent mutiple workers from running.

Comment: As far as settings go look at the Readme for delayed job under the heading `Gory Details`

Comment: I tried your code, but, in order to make DJ to work I must type in the console the `RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job stop` command. If I put your code in the `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb` file it doesn't work.

Comment: Create a new question with the code samples and the error you are getting, we can continue over there.

Comment: I made that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994479/initialize-the-delay-jobs-gem-using-rails-env-development-script-delayed-job-n