# Initialize the Delayed Jobs gem by starting the workers on application start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, initialization, delayed-job

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I am trying to setup the [delay_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem. All works if, after rebooting the Apache2 server, I run in the Terminal\Console following commands:

```
RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job stop
RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job -n 2 start
```

However, since I always want to start the workers on application start, in my `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb` I add the following code (that handles both development and production mode):

```
if Rails.env.development?
  system 'RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job stop'
  system 'RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job -n 2 start'
elsif Rails.env.production?
  system 'RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop'
  system 'RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n 2 start'
end
```

However, by using the above code and after re-rebooting the Apache2 server, the DJ gem doesn't work anymore as expected. That is, it doesn't process jobs as it makes when I run the above command lines in the Terminal\Console.

**How can I make DJ to work correctly? What is the problem?**

P.S.: I would like to do that in order to automatize processes.

---

It seams that the above code in the `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb` file doesn't "create" the "pids" files related to DJ in the `RAILS_ROOT/tmp/pids` directory. Those are created only by running the above command lines manually. Why this happens?

---

**UPDATE** for *@Devin M*

My `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb` contains:

```
# Options
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 2
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 5
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 1.hour
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test?

if Rails.env.development?
  system "RAILS_ENV=development #{Rails.root.join('script','delayed_job')} stop"
  system "RAILS_ENV=development #{Rails.root.join('script','delayed_job')} -n 2 start"
elsif Rails.env.production?
  system "RAILS_ENV=production #{Rails.root.join('script','delayed_job')} stop"
  system "RAILS_ENV=production #{Rails.root.join('script','delayed_job')} -n 2 start"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
system "RAILS_ENV=production #{Rails.root.join('script','delayed_job')} stop"
system "RAILS_ENV=production #{Rails.root.join('script','delayed_job')} -n 2 start"
```

Testing it in the console produced this output which indicates it should work:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.9)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > Rails.root.join('script','delayed_job')
 => #<Pathname:/home/devin/testsoapp/script/delayed_job> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > "RAILS_ENV=production #{Rails.root.join('script','delayed_job')} -n 2 start"
 => "RAILS_ENV=production /home/devin/testsoapp/script/delayed_job -n 2 start" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 >
```

Comment: By using your code, the resulting test output is the same as your (of course path references of my application are different), but it still doesn't work. That is, it still doesn't create "pid" files in the `RAILS_ROOT/tmp/pids`. Note that at this time I am running the application on my local machine in development mode.

Comment: If you run `"RAILS_ENV=production #{Rails.root.join('script','delayed_job')} -n 2 start"` in your applications console and then run the returned string as a command in a terminal does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't works. Note that at this time I am running the application on my local machine in development mode.

Comment: In development mode if in the console I run `RAILS_ENV=development #{Rails.root.join('script','delayed_job')} -n 2 start"` it works as expected. In development mode if I use the same code in the `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb` file (as reported in the question), it doesn't work. Does this behavior depend on some user permission on directory and files (my local machine is a MAC OS running Snow Leopard)?

Comment: In `delayed_job.log` and in `development.log` files I have no errors. It is very strange (for me) that it doesn't work by putting the `RAILS_ENV=development #{Rails.root.join('script','delayed_job')} -n 2 start` in the initializer file and it works by running the command line version.

Comment: @DevinM let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2262/discussion-between-backo-and-devin-m)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can do that because when you start the '/script/delayed_job', the rails environment will be loaded, causing the 'config/initializers/delayed_job.rb' file to be executed again.
You can see this results in an infinite loop.
Also each time you invoke rake, for example: 'rake db:migrate', it would initialize delayed_jobs.

You can hack around it with this:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  if(!File.exists?(Rails.root.join('tmp','pids', 'delayed_job.pid')))
    system "echo \"Starting delayed_jobs...\""
    system "./script/delayed_job start &"
  else
    system "echo \"delayed_jobs is running\""
  end
end
```

With the '&' the delayed_job script is run in background, on a separate process than rails.
Subsequent calls to rake will skip launching delayed_jobs if its already running.
You'll still have some problems if, for some reason, that file is not deleted when delayed_jobs terminates.

The command 
    /script/delayed_job status
will detect if that's the case, but you can't run it inside this 'config/initializers/delayed_job.rb' file because it would cause an infinite loop :(

Comment: Listen to this guy " but you can't run it inside this 'config/initializers/delayed_job.rb' file because it would cause an infinite loop"

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem where the initializing delayed_job process was running though its initializers before creating the pid file (i.e. delayed_job.pid in case of a single worker and delayed_job.0.pid delayed_job.1.pid etc. in case of many workers)

So I resorted to creating my own lock file as such:

```
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 2
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 5
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 4.hour
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test?

workers = 2


if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.development?
  # Check if the delayed job process is already running
  # Since the process loads the rails env, this file will be called over and over
  # Unless this condition is set.
  pids = Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('tmp','pids','*'))

  system "echo \"delayed_jobs INIT check\""
  if pids.select{|pid| pid.start_with?(Rails.root.join('tmp','pids','delayed_job.init').to_s)}.empty?

    f = File.open(Rails.root.join('tmp','pids','delayed_job.init'), "w+") 
    f.write(".")
    f.close
    system "echo \"Restatring delayed_jobs...\""
    system "RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env} #{Rails.root.join('bin','delayed_job')} stop"
    system "RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env} #{Rails.root.join('bin','delayed_job')} -n #{workers} start"
    system "echo \"delayed_jobs Workers Initiated\""
    File.delete(Rails.root.join('tmp','pids','delayed_job.init')) if File.exist?(Rails.root.join('tmp','pids','delayed_job.init'))

  else
    system "echo \"delayed_jobs is running\""
  end
end
```

file: config\initializers\delayed_job.rb

***Note: will not work for windows!***