# Ruby On Rails active record delayed job running on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, process, background, delayed-job

> Im trying delayed job to work on production(Using Windows, Rails
>   4.2.5, ActiveRecord as my ORM) In my gemfile I add the following:

```
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'
```

> In development to use delayed job I type this in cmd.

```
rake jobs:work
```

> And its working fine. To use in production, I add bin/delayed_job.rb,
>   and in my initialiazer I add delayed_job.rb. Inside my
>   initialiazers/delayed_job.rb

```
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 60
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 3
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 5.minutes
Delayed::Worker.read_ahead = 10
Delayed::Worker.default_queue_name = 'default'
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test?
Delayed::Worker.raise_signal_exceptions = :term
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log',        'delayed_job.log'))

if Rails.env.production?
    system 'RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start'
    system 'RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job stop'
end
```

When I run the program in production DelayedJob just creating record in the database, but it is not running. There is no logs recorded in my delayed_job.log

Here is updated code.

```
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 60
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 3
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 5.minutes
Delayed::Worker.read_ahead = 10
Delayed::Worker.default_queue_name = 'default'
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test?
Delayed::Worker.raise_signal_exceptions = :term
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'delayed_job.log'))

if Rails.env.production?
    system "RAILS_ENV=production #{Rails.root}/bin/delayed_job start"
    system "RAILS_ENV=production #{Rails.root}/bin/delayed_job start"
end
```

I just change the Rails_env=development to production and added the Rails.root, Iforgot to say that Im using Jruby 9.0.4.0 (2.2.2)

Comment: Please see this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994479/initialize-the-delayed-jobs-gem-by-starting-the-workers-on-application-start

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the absolute path.
You should also only have one delayed_job start call.
If you want two instances of delayed_job you should instead pass on the number of workers (updated my example to show that)
Try to change it to:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  system "RAILS_ENV=development #{Rails.root}/bin/delayed_job start --number_of_workers=2"
end
```

After that change, and a restart in production, run:

```
$ ps -ef | grep delayed_job
```

...should show:

```
$ your_user 4242 1 0 10:12 ? 00:00:00 delayed_job
```

Comment: Can you update your question with how the code looks right now please?